# Unable to access Tomcat Apache server from remote machine using browser

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, remote-access

I am having Apache Tomcat 5.5 version installed on a remote machine. Application is using Java servlets and mysql database. I need to access that pages using a specific ip address(http://192.168.2.2:8080/myapps) on any system.

Please provide me a references link or steps to access remote server web pages.

Regards,

Comment: Define "remote", you're using a local IP address.

Comment: I presume you tried to access it and it didn't work? What was the error? Is the Tomcat running on that machine? Were you able to open the webpage locally on Tomcat machine as http://localhost:8080/myapps?

Comment: Yes i am able to access it on the remote machine. http://locahost:8080/myapps/

Comment: Remote means I am accessing that machine using Remote Desktop Connection on my windows 7 machine. and the machine on which java application is setup is also windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you have either a firewall on the machine with tomcat on it, you have its IP address wrong, or you are on a network which cant connect to it.

Can you access it on the machine it is on (ie, the one where you can access it as localhost:8080/myapps) with the remote address - `http://192.168.2.2:8080/myapps`?
If not the address is wrong.

If the browser can't access 192.168.2.2 at all it means you have a firewall on that machine or that you are trying it from an address that doesn't start 192.168.

**EDIT**:

the address 192.168.x.x is a 'private address', which means nothing outside that address range can connect to it, and it can't go onto the internet. If you want to access it from the internet, you need a way to translate a public address (such as the one you listed xxx.125.xxx.158) to your private address, such as a router with port forwarding set up.

Without that you won't be able to connect to it.

Comment: Yes Woody. the remote computer is not on my network. but I want to access it. I can access the web pages from tomcat server by using localhost and ip address url.

Comment: @محمدخليل If it's on a *separate network* then you won't be able to get to it using a local IP address, you'd have to get an external IP address that you can connect to it through.

Comment: I am unable to view my web pages using external ip address xx.125.xx.158. i have checked from whatismyip.com any solution to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem in my windows 2012 server OS, I just have added an exception to port on which the tomcat apache was running.

for adding exception to port use the following step

1) Open Windows Firewall by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, and then clicking Control Panel. In the search box, type firewall, and then click Windows Firewall.

2) In the left pane, click Advanced settings. Administrator permission required If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.

3) In the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security dialog box, in the left pane, click Inbound Rules, and then, in the right pane, click New Rule.

4) Now select port and click next, now enter your port in specific local ports OR check on All local port. That's ALL

Comment: Finally it worked for me when I switched off the domain profile firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the `allow` attribute value in the **context.xml** file, present in **webapps/manager/meta-inf** folder.

Old configuration

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />
```

change to new Configuration

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+" />
```

This will allow access to manager **remotely from all IP addresses for login**. Further you won't get 403 access denied page